# R error: Overfull \hbox (pt too wide) in paragraph at lines

Tags: r, pdf, knitr

I am working through a homework assignment and with each line of code I write I like to compile my pdf on knitr to make sure everything is running smoothly. However, When I compile something very simple without any R code and just words, I get an "Overfull \hbox (5.68623pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 54--55" error and my pdf does not run. The weirder part is that my error says "at lines 54--55" when my entire document is only 9 lines long. I have googled my error and I have found things like "tabularx" and I have tried it but I continually get this error. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you so much everyone, I really appreciate it!
Lizzie

my code:

```
      \documentclass{article}

      \begin{document}

      THE FOLLOWING IS FROM HOMEWORK 1 -- PLEASE DO NOT GRADE

      Part a: obtain estimated regression function

      \end{document}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Your code runs without an error on my system.

Comment: Roland, that's what I was afraid of hearing. So I assume that there is something wrong with my machine then? My knitr was working perfectly before. Thank you so much for trying! I really do appreciate it.

Comment: lovebug, please prefix Roland's username with an "@" symbol, otherwise he won't get your message (yours don't need because you're the OP).

Answer (score -1):

The error message you are encountering, "Overfull \hbox (xxx pt too wide) in alignment at lines," is a common issue in LaTeX. This error occurs when the content inside a box (such as a table cell or a paragraph) exceeds the allowed width of the box. The number in parentheses (e.g., xxx pt) indicates how much the box is overflowing.

This issue often happens when LaTeX is unable to properly break lines or adjust the spacing to fit the content within the specified width. The alignment mentioned in the error message could be related to a table or a similar environment where content is supposed to be arranged in columns.

To fix this error, you can try one or more of the following approaches:

1. Adjust the width: If the overfull \hbox occurs in a specific table cell, you can manually adjust the width of the column to accommodate the content. Use the p{width} specifier in the tabular environment, where width is the desired width of the column.

Example:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|c|p{3cm}|}
  % Your table content here
\end{tabular}
```

1. Improve line breaking: If the issue is within regular text paragraphs, consider improving line breaking by rephrasing sentences or adjusting wordings slightly.
2. Hyphenation: Enclose problematic words inside \mbox{} to prevent line breaking within that specific word. Alternatively, you can use the \hyphenation{} command in your preamble to guide LaTeX on how to hyphenate certain words.
3. Use `\sloppy`: If you have a long paragraph with difficult-to-break content, you can use the `\sloppy` command before the problematic paragraph. This will make LaTeX more lenient in inter-word spacing to avoid overfull boxes, but it might affect the overall layout of the document.

Example:

```latex
\begin{sloppypar}
  % Your paragraph with problematic content here
\end{sloppypar}
```

5. Reword or reformat: If all else fails, you may need to reword your content or reformat the document to prevent the error from occurring.

Always remember to recompile your LaTeX document after making changes to see if the error has been resolved. In some cases, you may need to apply a combination of the above approaches to fix the issue.

Comment: Is this by any chance a ChatGPT-generated answer?  In any case, it doesn't seem to address the OP's question ...

Comment: I got the same problem in a different context (with a tabular table). This answer help me to understand what I was doing wrong. So, I thing it could help others (like this user that did not get an answer in seven years). In my case (that could be the case of any other), the code compiles. You are always welcome to give a better answer though.

Comment: I can appreciate this, but I don't think it really answers the OP's question, and your question sounds like it belongs on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ rather than Stack Overflow ... ???

Comment: I get to this question by "googling" about Overfull \hbox (xxx pt too wide). I answered it just before closing the tab after I get the solution to my issue. OP had the same problem, but caused by another "item/library" . The solution in both cases is the same: Adjust the width. I put an PoC with the tabular, I am sure OP could find the way of doing the same with R. Anyways I agree It is not the best fitted answer I  have given

Comment: I'll agree to disagree.